# Counting characters in a specific text file

Tags: powershell, scripting, character, counting

I need to count the vocals, consonants and all other characters in a specific text file.

I created a script that counts the vocals and consonants, but I can't figure out how to count the rest of the characters.

The goal is to count ALL characters, even if they're from another language, like Icelandic characters and signs like comma, full stop and exclamation mark.

Here's my current code:

```
Clear-Host
$vocal = (Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\POWERSHELL\testfil.txt | Select-String -Pattern "a|e|i|o|u|æ|ø|å" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
$vocal = (Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\POWERSHELL\testfil.txt | Select-String -Pattern "b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|z" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
$sign = $sign - $vocal - $consonant
if ($consonant -ge $vocal -ge $sign) {
  "`nThere are $vocal vocals, $consonant consonants and $sign other signs in the chosen document.`n"
} else {
    break
}
```

I realize I need some way to count the total amount of characters, and then subtract the vocals and consonants (and spaces) to find the third number, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Side notes: The 2nd assignment `$vocal = ...` should be `$consonant = ...`. Also, your comparison `$consonant -ge $vocal -ge $sign` won't work. PowerShell doesn't support daisy-chaining comparisons like that. You need `$consonant -ge $vocal -and $vocal -ge $sign`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Measure-Object` to get the total characters in a file by using the `-Characters` switch (Note: in PowerShell 7 this switch is named `-Character`).

The following then returns the value of this property to a variable:

```
$TotalChars = (Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\POWERSHELL\testfil.txt | Measure-Object -Character).Characters

$sign = $TotalChars - $vocal -$consonant
```

If you want to discount the whitespace characters you can also use the `-ignorewhitespace` switch with `Measure-Object`.

Comment: Hm, this does seem to work, but does it count the spaces as characters too? i think i'd like to remove the spaces from the count.

Comment: See the edit I added at the end. Just use `-ignorewhitespace` also on `Measure-Object` to exclude spaces.

Comment: Fantastic! This did the trick :) 

Thanks a bunch, Mark Wragg!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to count whitespace characters you could use a pattern `\S` to match single non-whitespace characters for calculating the total character count. You may also want to use character classes instead of alternations, and avoid reading the input file multiple times.

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt'
$all       = ($txt | Select-String -Pattern '\S' -AllMatches).Matches.Count
$vocal     = ($txt | Select-String -Pattern '[aeiouæøå]' -AllMatches).Matches.Count
$consonant = ($txt | Select-String -Pattern '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]' -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark Wragg's answer worked perfectly.

All i really needed was the ".characters" phrase.

Here's the finished code:

```
clear-host
$vocal=(Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\POWERSHELL\testfil.txt | Select-String -Pattern "a|e|i|o|u|æ|ø|å" -AllMatches).matches.count
$consonant=(Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\POWERSHELL\testfil.txt | Select-String -Pattern "b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|z" -AllMatches).matches.count
$TotalChars=(Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\POWERSHELL\testfil.txt | Measure-Object -ignorewhitespace -Character).Characters 
$sign = $TotalChars - $vocal -$consonant
if($consonant -ge $vocal -ge $sign){"`nThere are $vocal vocals, $consonant consonants and $sign other characters in the chosen document.`n"}
else{break}
```

Note: this assignment was originally made in the Danish language, hence the "æ ø å" in the vocal category. If anyone else needs to do similar scripts, I apologize if I've left some strange words or letters in the script ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$Vokaler=(Get-Content D:\script.txt | Select-String -Pattern "a|e|i|o|u|y|æ|ø|å" -AllMatches).matches.count
```

Just a quick reminder for anyone interested, remember "y", since this wasn't added in the previous responses.

Comment: These are already part of OP solved ("vocals") - unless I misunderstand, this is not an answer to their question.

Comment: In the previous response from op, the code works just fine, but it did not search the selected document for the vokal "y", Hence the little snipped i highlighted had the addition of "y" to the string.

It was nothing but a simple reminder of the existence of "y"